# Draw Square With Polar Coordinates in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, math, programming-languages, opengl-3

How can I draw a square with polar coordinates in OpenGL?

#### I know these Equations:

```
 x = r * cos ( theta ) 
 y = r * sin ( theta )
 r = n * cos ( theta )
```

#### My code:

```
float baseX = width / 2.f; 
float baseY = height / 2.f
int n = 7;
glBegin(GL_POINTS);{
    for (float tempAngle = 0.0 ; tempAngle <= PI/4 ; tempAngle++) {
        radius = n * cos(PI/4);
        x = baseX + radius * cos(tempAngle);
        y = baseY + radius * sin(tempAngle);
        glVertex2f(x, y);
    }
}glEnd();
```

Comment: These equations do only create a sphere if you sample exactly four points from them, with a angle distance of PI/2 each. What you do render is a series of points which lie on a sphere arc segment. I don't know what you try to achieve here, but it seems pointless to use polar coordinates here.

Comment: @derhass: OP asks for a square (equilateral rectangle). Given that polar coordinates make even less sense.

Comment: Whoops, I meant "square" (and "circle" for the second instance) in that above comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
int n = 70;
int i = 1;
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);{
    for (float tempAngle = 0.0 ; tempAngle <= 2 * PI ; tempAngle += PI/8) {
        radius = n * cos(tempAngle);
        x = baseX + radius * cos(tempAngle);
        y = baseY + radius * sin(tempAngle);
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            glVertex2f(x, y);
        i++;
    }
}glEnd();
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope we all realize that this is a purely theoretical exercise, and is not a reasonable way of drawing a square with OpenGL. But I thought it might be fun anyway, so here we go.

I don't think your formula is correct. Draw the right side of a square in a coordinate system, which is a vertical line at `x = 1.0`. If you then look at the distance from the origin of a given point on that line, depending on `theta`, you see that:

```
cos(theta) = 1.0 / r
```

Which quickly leads to the value of `r` for the square in a polar coordinate system:

```
r = 1.0 / cos(theta)
```

Based on this, here is code for drawing a square using polar coordinates. `side2` is half the side length of the square:

```
const float PI_F = static_cast<float>(M_PI);
const unsigned DIV_COUNT = 10;
const float ANG_INC = 0.5f * PI_F / static_cast<float>(DIV_COUNT);

glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);

for (unsigned iDiv = 0; iDiv < DIV_COUNT; ++iDiv)
{
    float ang = -0.25f * PI_F + static_cast<float>(iDiv) * ANG_INC;
    float r = side2 / cos(ang);
    glVertex2f(r * cos(ang), r * sin(ang));
}

for (unsigned iDiv = 0; iDiv < DIV_COUNT; ++iDiv)
{
    float ang = -0.25f * PI_F + static_cast<float>(iDiv) * ANG_INC;
    float r = side2 / cos(ang);
    glVertex2f(r * -sin(ang), r * cos(ang));
}

for (unsigned iDiv = 0; iDiv < DIV_COUNT; ++iDiv)
{
    float ang = -0.25f * PI_F + static_cast<float>(iDiv) * ANG_INC;
    float r = side2 / cos(ang);
    glVertex2f(r * -cos(ang), r * -sin(ang));
}

for (unsigned iDiv = 0; iDiv < DIV_COUNT; ++iDiv)
{
    float ang = -0.25f * PI_F + static_cast<float>(iDiv) * ANG_INC;
    float r = side2 / cos(ang);
    glVertex2f(r * sin(ang), r * -cos(ang));
}

glEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you mean by your question. A square has four corners, which correspond to four vertices when drawing. Fixed function OpenGL uses cartesian coordinates (it's trivial to implement a vertex shader that ingests polar or spherical coordinates and properly transforms to cartesian clip space).

So what exactly is your question. I can see only one meaningful way to interpret this question: *"What are the coordinates of a square's corners in polar coordinates?"* However I don't see how you relate that to OpenGL in your mental model.